# Construct an 2D array of contiguous elements comparing master and incident arrays

Tags: javascript

**Requirement**:

Based on `mainArray` which contains the master list of items, and `compArray` which has items of interest; construct a 2 dimensional third array that contains the array of contiguous elements.

The purpose of this requirement is for plotting poly-line on map wherever an incident occurred in contiguous manner, plotted using the `finalArray` of locations.

**Example**:

```js
const mainArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
const compArray = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 15];

// produces finalArray
[[ 1, 2, 3 ],[ 6, 7 ],[ 11, 12, 13 ],[ 15 ]]
```

**My current solution**:

```js
console.clear();

const mainArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
const compArray = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 15];
let compArrayIndex = 0;
let finalArray = [];
let currentArray = null;

for (let i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++) {
  const e = mainArray[i];

  if (e === compArray[compArrayIndex]) {
    if (!currentArray) {
      currentArray = [];
    }
    currentArray.push(e);
    compArrayIndex++;
  } else {
    if (currentArray) {
      finalArray.push([...currentArray]);
      currentArray = null;
    }
  }
}

if (currentArray) {
  finalArray.push([...currentArray]);
  currentArray = null;
}

console.log(mainArray);
console.log(compArray);
console.log('finl arr:');
for (let i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {
  const e = finalArray[i];
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Why does this question have close votes? The problem is explained, there's an example and the code is there and seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Good algorithm

Your solution is good, however its implementation is somewhat poor.

### Clear requirements

It is very unclear what inputs to expect so I must add...

The input arrays are sorted and contain unique values, I must assume a requirement that is true.

I deduce this from your code as if the above was not true your code would fail.

### Style & code

- The variable names are too long. Remember code is always in context and if you are handling arrays do you really need to add that in their names?
- Don't copy the array, just push it to the result. `finalArray.push([...currentArray]);` can be `finalArray.push(currentArray);` The copy halves the performance of your code (see below)
- Use `undefined` rather than `null`
- Simplify the code by using `else if` when possible. You have `} else { if (currentArray) {` which can be `} else if (currentArray) {`
- `finalArray` should be a constant.
- Don't add code that is not needed. The last statement block up assign `null` to `currentArray` yet the variable is never used after that line.

Apart from the above points your algorithm is good as it has low complexity (if you use `finalArray.push(currentArray)` you halve the complexity as [...currentArray] requires iteration of each item).

You missed the opportunity to exit early. If you pass the end of the either arrays you know that no more items need to be added, however you continue to the end of the first array, which if longer than the second could mean many rundundent iterations.

If you change the for loop to...

```
for (let i = 0; i < mainArray.length && compArrayIndex < compArray.length; i++) {
```

...you gain a reduction in overall complexity.

### Cleaning up your solution

Thus we can rewrite your algorithm as

```
function extractRuns(main, comp) { 
    var seq, j = 0;
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < main.length && j < comp.length; i++) {
        const e = main[i];
        if (e === comp[j]) {
            if (!seq) { seq = [] }
            seq.push(e);
            j++;
        } else if (seq) {
            result.push(seq);
            seq = undefined;
        }
    }
    if (seq) { result.push(seq) }
    return result;
}
```

### Short is not always best

I must point out that the [existing answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/208583/120556) by guest271314 is very poor as it has very bad complexity by using `Array.includes` and is forced to iterate each item in the main array as it has no way to exit early from `Array.reduce`.

### Rewrite

I personally would have written the solution as below as it gains a little performance (not by reduced complexity) via an inner while loop. (I am a bit of an off grid performance freak :) )

```
function extractRuns(main, comp) { // both arrays must be sorted and contain unique values
    var m = 0, c = 0, seq;  // c and m are indexes 
    const result = [], mLen = main.length, cLen = comp.length;
    while (m < mLen && c < cLen) {
        const a = main[m], b = comp[c];
        if (a === b) {
            c ++;
            m ++;
            result.push(seq = [a]);
            while (m < mLen && r < cLen && main[m] === comp[c]) {
                seq.push(main[m ++]);
                c ++;
            }
        } else if (b < a) { c ++ }
        else { m ++ }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But I think your solution is far more readable and only a few % points slower to not be an issue.

Comment: I agree with the review, although the long variable names were just for making my current solutions intentions more clear in the question. Thank you for the review.

Comment: @Vijay Re long names, Understandable but we must take the code at face value. It is assumed that the posted code is working production (release) code. On that I did forget to make a point that it should also have been as a `function` but again I understand that you wrote it as an example.

Comment: @Blindman67 _"I must point out that the existing answer by guest271314 is very poor"_  Your answer should stand on its own without any reference to another users' answer. You should be able to remove that portion of text from your answer without affecting the remainder of your answer. At a minimum instead of referring to this user in you answer you could have simply suggested to use `.find()` instead of `.includes()` as that appears to be the only criticism of the answer that you are citing. Did not ask you to review this users' answer though since you insisted on doing so do so constructively

Comment: This is a good answer but I realllyyy can't agree with "The variable names are too long"

Comment: @IEatBagels How does `mainArray` improve on `main` its an array why add it to the name.  `compArrayIndex`  adds nothing to the readability of a 17 line function over  `j` as a standard iteration index name. Long names make long lines that often means breaking lines apart that could be single line statements and expressions. Good names are short, don't include type, and are always read in context of the code they are declared in from which comes most of the semantic meaning. Long names are for long functions with many variables declared off page, and globals, both of which are bad.

Answer (score 2):

The code could be reduced to a single line by utilizing `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```js
const mainArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
const compArray = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 15];

const finalArray = mainArray.reduce((a, b) => {
  // `c` is boolean result of checking if `compArray` includes `b`
  // `x` is first, and if matching elements found, last array in `finalResult`
  const [c, x] = [compArray.includes(b), a[a.length - 1]];
  // if `c` push `b` to last array of `a`
  if (c) x.push(b)
  // else if `x.length` push a new array to `a`
  else if (x.length) a.push([]);
  // return `a`
  return a;
}, [[]]); // pass initial array containing single array `a` to `reduce`

console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: To filter empty arrays in the case of `[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13]` you can chain `.filter(n=>n.length)`

Comment: I must point out your answer is not really a review, that the solution you give is O(n^2) while the op's is O(n), and that the comments are too much.. I would have down voted if you were not a newbie but rather I upvote and encourage you to keep posting, keeping these points in mind of course.   Really!!! `.// return 'a'` for `return a;` and `// else if `x.length` push a new array to `a`` for `else if (x.length) a.push([]);`

Comment: @Blindman67 Not sure what you mean? How did you determine O(n^2)  and  O(n)? Is your only criticism the use of `.includes()` instead of `.find()`? "down" vote is meaningless to this user.

Comment: `Array.includes` or `Array.find` are both iterative searches, when done inside another iteration the worst case is O(n^2) with n the mean array size. Plus there is no way to exit early from `Array.reduce` if the other array is shorter.